# JavaScript resize snowflakes before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to see if I can resize the images before the page loads. I can't get it to load before the website is loaded. I added a code snippet so you can try it out.

I want to do this so they don't resize as they drop I want them resized already before they drop.

Here is the code:

```js
// the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

  var SnowFlake = function(expireCallback) {
    var that = this;
    var vector = [0, 0];
    var position = [0, 0];
    var isOnscreen = false;
    var $element = $('<div class="snowflake" style="position: fixed; color:#fff; text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 1px 1px 2px;"><img src="http://isnocafe.com/dev2/_splashpage/images/snowflake.png" width="30px" /></div>');

    var updatePosition = function() {
      $element.css({
        left: position[0],
        top: position[1]
      });
    };

    var widths = ["8px", "15px", "25px", "35px"];
    $(".snowflake img").each(function(i, e) {
      var width = widths[Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) - 1];
      $(e).css('width', width);
    });

    var updateAttributes = function(size, opacity) {
      $element.css({
        width: size,
        opacity: opacity
      });
    };

    var checkExpired = function(bounds) {
      if (position[0] > bounds.x || position[1] > bounds.y) {
        isOnscreen = false;
        $element.remove();
        expireCallback(that);
      }
    };

    this.spawn = function(newVector, startPos, size, opacity) {
      vector = newVector;
      position = startPos;
      updateAttributes(size, opacity);
      updatePosition();
      $('body').append($element);
      isOnscreen = true;
    };

    this.render = function(interval, bounds) {
      if (isOnscreen) {
        position[0] = position[0] + (interval * vector[0]);
        position[1] = position[1] + (interval * vector[1]);
        checkExpired(bounds);
        updatePosition();
      }
    };
  };


  var SnowFlakeEmitter = function(settings) {
    var flakes = [];
    var reclaimedFlakes = [];
    var lastTime = 0;

    var shouldSpawnNewFlake = function() {
      return (Math.random() * 700) < settings.intensity;
    };

    var getScreenBounds = function() {
      return {
        x: $(window).width(),
        y: $(window).height()
      };
    };

    var randomBetween = function(min, max) {
      return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
    };

    var newFlakeVector = function() {
      var x = randomBetween(settings.driftRange[0], settings.driftRange[1]);
      var y = randomBetween(settings.speedRange[0], settings.speedRange[1]);
      return [x, y];
    };

    var newFlakePosition = function(bounds) {
      var x = randomBetween(-20, bounds.x + 20);
      var y = -20;
      return [x, y];
    };

    var reclaimFlake = function(flake) {
      reclaimedFlakes.push(flake);
    };

    var getFlake = function() {
      var flake;
      if (reclaimedFlakes.length) {
        flake = reclaimedFlakes.pop();
      } else {
        flake = new SnowFlake(reclaimFlake);
        flakes.push(flake);
      }
      return flake;
    };

    var spawnNewFlake = function(bounds) {
      var flake = getFlake();
      flake.spawn(
        newFlakeVector(),
        newFlakePosition(bounds),
        randomBetween(settings.sizeRange[0], settings.sizeRange[1]),
        randomBetween(settings.opacityRange[0], settings.opacityRange[1])
      );
    };

    var getInterval = function() {
      var time = Date.now();
      var interval = 0;

      if (lastTime) {
        interval = (time - lastTime) / 1000;
      }

      lastTime = time;
      return interval;
    };

    this.render = function() {
      var i, l = flakes.length;
      var interval = getInterval();
      var bounds = getScreenBounds();

      if (shouldSpawnNewFlake()) {
        spawnNewFlake(bounds);
      }

      for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        flakes[i].render(interval, bounds);
      }
    };
  };

  // Create the defaults once
  var pluginName = "snow",
    defaults = {
      intensity: 10,
      sizeRange: [10, 20],
      opacityRange: [0.5, 1],
      driftRange: [-2, 2],
      speedRange: [25, 80]
    };

  // The actual plugin constructor
  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or
    // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
    // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
    // future instances of the plugin
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  // Avoid Plugin.prototype conflicts
  $.extend(Plugin.prototype, {
    init: function() {
      var snow = new SnowFlakeEmitter(this.settings);
      if (window.requestAnimationFrame) {
        function render() {
          snow.render();
          window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
      } else {
        setInterval(function() {
          snow.render();
        }, 1 / 60);
      }
    }
  });

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
      }
    });
    return this;
  };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>jQuery Snow Basic Demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.snow.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .snowflake {
      -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
      animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes spin {
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #000;">
  <div id="main"></div>
  <script>
    jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("body").snow({
        intensity: 40,
        sizeRange: [12, 30],
        opacityRange: [0.4, 1],
        driftRange: [10, 20],
        speedRange: [55, 120]
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you hide the images by default you could resize and then show. Also, page load could include the loading of pictures, so you might be trying to resize pictures that don't exist on the page yet

Comment: You think you can show me how